# fortran undefined reference to popcnt_

Tags: fortran, fortran90

i am trying to compile a fortran 90 program which has a call to POPCNT as follows:

```
 ...
 print *, popcnt(127)
 ...
```

by compiling it as follows:

```
 gfortran prog.f90
```

it gives me the following:

```
 ...: undefined reference to `popcnt_'
```

plz can anyone suggest the correct way of compiling? thanks.

Comment: is `popcnt` a user-defined function?  if so, where is it located?  if not in `prog.f90`, you have to compile that and also link both together.  let us know where it is.

Comment: @yosukesabai http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/POPCNT.html thanks in advance!

Comment: can your gfortran take -std=f2008 option?  i.e. `gfortran -std=2008 prog.f90`?  my version both on cygwin and redhat dont recognize potcnt and dont recognize -std=2008 option.  so maybe you have to get the latest version of gfortran somehow (my version is GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52))

Comment: @yosukesabai i did compile it using "gfortran -std=f2008 prog.f90", it still says undefined reference to popcnt.

Comment: And i tested with pgf95 (www.pgroup.com) and i got some numbers printed in three lines.  so look like support of f2008 feature of your particular version of compiler.

Comment: @yosukesabai how can i install pgf95 on ubuntu? thanks in advance!

Comment: you can download pgfortran from www.pgroup.com, and they have trial version that works 14 days.  you'd also try getting newer gfortran from http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#GNU.2BAC8-Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

support for `bitcnt` is added in version 4.6
http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran#GCC4.6.  So you have to find newer executable, or compile your own.